# How to show if there exists a global frame for a vector bundle, then the vector bundle is trivial.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\pi: E\to M$ be a vector bundle.

For each $p \in M$, if $(\sigma_i(p))$ is a global frame, then we can construct a map from $E \to M\times \mathbb R^k$ via $\Phi(\sigma_i(p))=(p, e_i)$. This map is bijective and linear. So, it is a vector space isomorphism from the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p) \to \{p\}\times \mathbb R^k$.

How can I show $\Phi$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: A map of vector bundles which is an isomorphism on each fiber is a vector bundle isomorphism. You can find this in, say, Lee's book on smooth manifolds. But in this case you can also just explicitly write down the inverse map using your global frame.

Comment: I know what it means to be an isomorphism on each fiber, but what do you mean by vector bundle isomorphism?

Comment: an isomorphism - in any context - between $E, F$ is a map $f: E \to F$ (of the appropriate type) so that there exists a map $g: F \to E$ so that $fg$ and $gf$ are both the identity. A vector bundle map is a continuous map that is linear on each fiber. So what I am saying is that the set-level inverse map is automatically continuous (and obviously linear on each fiber).

Comment: Got it. I am using Lee's book, but I can't that claim anywhere.

Comment: Really? It is Proposition 10.26 in the section on vector bundle homomorphisms. The assumption that the map is bijective is the same as assuming the map is a vector space isomorphism on each fiber.

Comment: Ok I see now. Thanks. So now we need to show that $\Psi$ is a bundle homomorphism?